# std::filesystem trying to call an image file

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi, filesystems

```
        std::filesystem::current_path();
        const std::wstring filenm = std::filesystem::current_path() + L"\\bruh.jpeg";

        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)filenm + L"\\bruh.jpeg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

I know my code is scary, I've spent as much time as possible trying to figure out a possible solution. This is where I have left off. I am trying to call an image file to set the desktop background as that image. I'm trying to use `std::filesystem::current_path()` for the folder path and then call the image itself.

Comment: Third parameter should be a pointer to null-terminated string.

Comment: You probably meant `SystemParametersInfo(..., filenm.c_str(), ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there will be type incompatibilitieserrors in your code.

Modify the code as follows:

```
std::wstring fn1= std::filesystem::current_path()

std::wstring fn2= L"\\bruh.jpeg";

const std::wstring filenm = fn1 + fn2;

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)filenm.c_str(), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```